# Conditional fields for nested object in react-final-from (causes validation error)

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I'm using conditional fields with `react-final-form` as described in [here](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples#conditional-fields) for a nested object.

For some reasons it causes an error in validation, when the error message for the first field is sometimes returned as an object instead of a string. This happens unexpectedly, for example, sometimes, it displays a normal error message like this:

```
{
  "party": "Required",
  "bank": "Required"
}
```

But when I start to type something in either inputs, it turns into:

```
{
  "party": {
    "0": "R",
    "1": "e",
    "2": "q",
    "3": "u",
    "4": "i",
    "5": "r",
    "6": "e",
    "7": "d"
  },
  "bank": "Not found"
}
```

This field is then used in a condition:

```
<Condition when="party.data.type" is="INDIVIDUAL">
  <Field
    name="address"
    component={DadataAddress}
    label="Address"
    onSelect={suggestion => setAddress(suggestion)}
    initialQuery={this.state.data.address}
    query={values["address"] && values["address"].value}
    required
  />
  <Error name="address" />
</Condition>
```

If I delete condition component, everything works ok.

I wonder, if it is a bug or I'm doing something wrong. Here is a link to the example https://codesandbox.io/s/payform-wcsgz?fontsize=14. You can just type in any numbers in the inputs and scroll down to see the error messages.

If it's not a bug, how should I use nested objects in `<Condition when="">` above?

Comment: Why are you trying to maintain the form values yourself? That's exactly what React Final Form is for.

Comment: Yes, I know. But sometimes I need to initialize the form with the data from the server, that's why I'm using state. When the values are updated, I'm not using state any more. Is there any way to fix an error above?

Comment: Why on earth would it be converting the string to an object with integer keys!?!? That's so bizarre!

Comment: Should I file a GitHub issue instead?